# shapefile record has no attribute named bounds

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely, fiona

This is the code that I am using to print the bounds of my shapefile.

```
import fiona
import shapely
import shapely.geometry

fc = fiona.open("filename.shp")
shapefile_record = fc.next()
shape = shapely.geometry.asShape(shapefile_record['geometry'])
polygon = shapefile_record['geometry']
print polygon.bounds
```

However, I keep getting an error that says:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'bounds'
```

Can someone guide me as to where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your example, `polygon` is a standard Python dict object that represents a GeoJSON geometry, which only uses standard data types, with no fancy geospatial properties.

But you can convert `polygon` into a shapely geometry, as you have done with `shape`

```
polygon = shapefile_record['geometry']
shape = shapely.geometry.asShape(polygon)
print(shape.bounds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiona also has a bounds function.

```
>>> import fiona
>>> with fiona.open("input.shp") as src:
...     feat = next(src)
...     print fiona.bounds(feat)
```